# Adding punctuation while using Underscore reduce()

Tags: underscore.js

Here's the question I'm trying to answer:

*Write a function that takes an array of names and congratulates them. Make sure to use _.reduce as part of the function.


input: ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina']

output: 'Congratulations Steve, Sally, George, Gina!'*

**I don't know how to add that exclamation point at the end!  Here's my code:** 


var names = ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'];
var final = 'Congratulations ' + _.reduce(names, function(lastReduced, item, index, list) {
    return lastReduced + ', ' + item + '!';

});

console.log(final);

It outputs:

"Congratulations Steve, Sally!, George!, Gina!"  <=== obviously not correct!  Please help.

Comment: Just put it outside of the `reduce` call, just as you did with `'Congratulations '`?

Comment: `reduce` is very much unnecessary - that question is kinda ... *forced*. You could simply use join. `names.join(', ') + '!'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'];
var final = 'Congratulations ' + _.reduce(names, function(lastReduced, item, index, list) { return lastReduced + ', ' + item;
});
final += '!';
console.log(final);
```